# filename with newline in vim's Netrw Directory Listing

Tags: vim, gvim

Create a filename containing newline character:

```
$ touch $'a\nb'
```

When i do `vim .`, the filename split into multiline:
[image]

I can only select one line and press <kbd>enter</kbd>. Then it act as new file and show this line at the bottom of vim:

```
"~/note/test/b" [New File]
```

I think about <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> but can't make it work. Even <kbd>x</kbd> (Open gedit for this file) function is broken.

How can i select multiline filename in vim's Netrw Directory Listing ?

Answer (score 3):

The netrw plugin (at least partially) parses the output of remote commands (`ls`) to build the directory tree, and it internally mangles that information into the directory scratch buffer.

Support for such special characters isn't implemented yet; you can write the plugin's author, Charles Campbell, and suggest this enhancement. (Or even better, try to write a patch and submit this to him!)